# Idiosyncracy while extending django admin template

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates, django-views

On my django site, I decided to just use the admin templates for the UI, but I made a few tweaks like the site name, color, etc. even my custom views just extend admin/base_site.html I did this by creating templates/admin/base_site.html with the following code:

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Company Name' %}{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}
<style>
#header{ background-color: #a67d3d; border-bottom: solid 3px #f5deb3; }
#branding h1{ color: #fff; }
</style>
{% endblock %}

{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'My company' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block breadcrumbs %}
    {% include "breadcrumb.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

The entire admin site has my new title and colors. However, you can see I tried replacing the breadcrumbs bar with my own breadcrumb.html (which contains a custom nav bar). This only works on custom views that extend admin/base_site.html. the normal admin views don't replace the breadcrumbs (but they do have the new colors, company title, etc.). I can't figure out why this one piece isn't working? Moreover, I have a few custom change_form.html files. These also have the style changes, but no custom nav bar. But, if I put in the breadcrumbs block in these pages, it shows up just fine on those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around this by copying the original base.html file into my project's '/templates/admin/' folder, deleted the breadcrumbs block, added a "mynav" block, put my navbar there. This way my nav bar shows up on all pages, and when the lower pages try to put in a breadcrumb there's no block for them and it doesn't show up.

I don't like doing it this way but i can't think of another way. The way suggested by lazerscience would work, but I'd have to do an include in every single template (change_form, change_list, etc.). For others, i should mention, there is a "nav-global" block, but my navbar uses lists/css/jscript to display slideout menus and these menus weren't showing up if i put it in that block, not sure exactly why.

Answer (score 0):

The other admin templates, eg. `change_form.html` override the `breadcrumbs` block themselves, so you need to override it also in these templates (=override them and define your block in there).